# Is there a way to add Datatable row number in the Scenario Outline name in Karate

Tags: karate

I am using Examples Datatable using csv file as below:

Examples:
| read('file.csv') |

I got to know __num will have the row number of the iteration and able to print it using * print __num.

But when I try to add that row number to Scenario Outline title, its not giving the value. Its reporting as __num only.
Tried using # and ##, but no luck.
Tried below ways:
Scenario Outline: Scenario #(__num)
Scenario Outline: Scenario ##(__num)
Scenario Outline: Scenario '#(__num)'
Scenario Outline: Scenario '##__num'

I was able to add cell value into the title  but row number is not working.
Please help me in adding row number to the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if it works in the new version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

If it does not, please consider this as un-supported. You are welcome to contribute code to add this feature.